# Mockito, how to use real methods and get values

Tags: java, mockito

I am using mockito for my tests and thus i want the mock perform an increment on its AtomicIntegerField, here's a simplified code.

```
public class MockTest {

    private AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger( 0 );

    public int getAi(){
    return ai.get();
    }

    public void increment() {
    ai.getAndIncrement();
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
    MockTest mt = Mockito.mock( MockTest.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS );
    Mockito.when(mt.getAi()).thenCallRealMethod();
    Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(mt).increment();
    System.out.println(mt.getAi());
    mt.increment();
    System.out.println(mt.getAi());

    }
}
```

I tried thie CallRealMethod but i have got NullPointerException when the get is performed. I also read about using an Answer object but frow what i am not really sure about the arguements that uses.

Comment: You probably want a spy instead of a mock.

Comment: In such an example, you don't seem to even need a mock, you should test the real object!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Mockito documentation, **if the real implementation depends on specific state of the object then you're in trouble**. That is exactly your case, you are partially Mocking the class MockTest and then calling the method getAi() which depends on the state of the clase (ai).

http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html

As suggested in the comments, you can use a Spy though, which is the opposite approach, you use the real object and stub out only some methods. In your example it is not clear what you are trying to test, but this is how a spy looks like.

```
MockTest mt = Mockito.spy(new MockTest());

System.out.println(mt.getAi());
mt.increment();
System.out.println(mt.getAi());

// Output will be
// 0
// 1
```

And then if you need to stub out, let's say, the mt.getAi() method you could do it like this.

```
MockTest mt = Mockito.spy(new MockTest());
Mockito.when(mt.getAi()).thenReturn(100);

System.out.println(mt.getAi());
mt.increment();
System.out.println(mt.getAi());

// Output will be
// 100
// 100
```

Please take into account that a partial mock is normally a code smell except for very specific situations like when dealing with legacy code that is hard to change.

Hope this helps.